# Adding items to Python 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a empty  2d list which i dont know the length of or no of rows.

Animals has some number of items passed from function call.

In function startDocumentary_day(), For every function call, I have to append this each incoming animal list as each row in documentary list.

Eg:Animals can have  ['cow','tiger'], sometimes it can also be empty

```
  def startDocumentary_day():
       return documentary.append([])
  def add(documentary, animals):
       documentary[j for j in range(len(animals))].append(animals)
```

I tried this, But shows error, for this line 2 in add function.
Note :initially documentary is empty.

Comment: This question needs clarification. You have to tell us what the error is, "but shows error' is not helpful. Please break the question into steps.

Comment: You can't use a generator as a list index.

Comment: `append()` doesn't return anything, it makes no sense to `return` the result of `documentary.append([])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the `documentary` list, and append to each element.

```
def add(documentary, animals):
    for d in documentary:
        d.append(animals)
```

Comment: This doesnt work quite right, its adding in one list only. 
the actual solution is return documentary[len(documentary)-1].append(animals). so what this statement actually doing?

Comment: It was hard to tell what you were really trying to do. Can you update the question with sample data and the desired result?